# Non-Gaussian Hidden Markov Process

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

I'm using `EstimatedProcess` to simulate a `HiddenMarkovProcess` with two states using data derived from different ARIMA processes

```
EstimatedProcess[data, HiddenMarkovProcess[2, "Gaussian"]]
```

Are there other options for specifying the distribution of the `HiddenMarkovProcess` besides `"Gaussian"`? I can't find a list of the other options in Mathematica's documentation.

Thanks

Comment: One of the examples under Scope/Estimates of `HiddenMarkovProcess` gives an example for the Exponential distribution.  I appears that you can specify the name of any distribution (and that might likely include any "constructed" distribution using `TransformedDistribution`, etc.).

Comment: When I insert the string Guassian I'm really just telling it use  a single NormalDistribution[a,b] or is it using a family of Normal Distributions?

Comment: Yes.  Just try `EstimatedProcess[data, HiddenMarkovProcess[2, "Gaussian"]]` and `EstimatedProcess[data, HiddenMarkovProcess[2, NormalDistribution[a, b]]]` on the `HiddenMarkovProcess/Scope/Estimation` example.

Comment: Thinking about if this question should be closed:  In a way the answer "can be found" in the documentation but maybe "easily found" is not correct.  Also, using `NormalDistribution[a, b]`, `NormalDistribution[103.2, b]`, and `NormalDistribution[a, 17.6]` give exactly the same output but `NormalDistribution[0, 1]` results in an error.  So certainly more online documentation would be welcomed.  Also, there are no measures of precision given which for me makes the result being of unknown value (except for getting starting values for a function the does give estimates of precision).

Comment: I tried to do SkewedNormalDistrubution[a,b,c] and it did not work. It was taking an extremely long time. They need to work on this feature more.

Comment: I tried `SkewNormalDistribution` on the `TemporalData` in the `Scope/Estimation` section of `HiddenMarkovProcess` and it took 25 seconds to finish correctly (after two `FindRoot` warnings).

Comment: My answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292154/any-luck-estimating-a-multivariate-hidden-markov-process/292162#292162) may be helpful for fitting a HMM with arbitrary emission distributions

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little too late and also I am not claiming that it is the correct way, statistically speaking, for the HMM set-up. I am only presenting a possible programmatic way of answering the OP's question.

```
(*produce fake data*)
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1],100];

(*estimate the parameters of the first pdf you want*)
paramsP = 
 FindDistributionParameters[data, 
  StableDistribution[1, Subscript[\[Alpha], p], Subscript[\[Beta], p],
    Subscript[\[Mu], p], Subscript[\[Sigma], p]]]

(*estimate the parameters of the second pdf you want*)
paramsN = 
 FindDistributionParameters[data, 
  StableDistribution[1, Subscript[\[Alpha], n], Subscript[\[Beta], n],
    Subscript[\[Mu], n], Subscript[\[Sigma], n]]]

(*define the HMM set-up*)

class = HiddenMarkovProcess[{1/2, 
   1/2}, {{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 
    0.5}}, {StableDistribution[1, Subscript[\[Alpha], p], 
     Subscript[\[Beta], p], Subscript[\[Mu], p], Subscript[\[Sigma], 
     p]] /. paramsP, 
   StableDistribution[1, Subscript[\[Alpha], n], Subscript[\[Beta], 
     n], Subscript[\[Mu], n], Subscript[\[Sigma], n]] /. paramsN}]

(*estimate the HMM process*)
hmm = EstimatedProcess[data, class]

(*find the States*)
foundStates = FindHiddenMarkovStates[data, hmm, "PosteriorDecoding"]
```