# Any luck estimating a multivariate hidden Markov process?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, markov-chains, markov-process, estimation

I am having problems using EstimatedProcess to estimate a multivariate HiddenMarkovProcess. I'm following the work of a paper, so I know this method is feasible. In brief, given 2 economic variables: inflation and growth, it examines the different states of an economy.

I can use the Mathematica functions to build a reasonable model for each variable individually. However, I'm having problems when trying to build a joint model. Either, EstimatedProcess fails with a an error ("One or more data points are not in the support of the process"), or the HiddenMarkovProcess it returns has only univariate distributions.

Has anyone else had this problem? Are there working examples of this technique?

Here's a link to a notebook I'm using: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/56901a8a-ed94-48c9-ab02-985ef11c0016

Comment: Can you link the paper?

Comment: The paper is here: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391292

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to fit a 2-state `HiddenMarkovProcess` where the emission distributions from each state are both 2-variable `MultinormalDistribution`s.

Using my answer from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Mathematica/comments/17kq3tu/any_luck_estimating_a_multivariate_hidden_markov/k79q4ma/?context=3), we can do that by changing the input data to be `TemporalData`. You can directly use the dates as the time specifiers with `TemporalData`, but I prefer to work with raw numbers so I changed the dates to reflect how many months they are away from the start (e.g. `dates = data[All, "Date"] // Normal;` and then `times = (dates - dates[[1]])/Quantity[1, "month"];`)

```
dates = data[All, "Date"] // Normal;
times = (dates - dates[[1]])/Quantity[1, "month"];
econ = data[All, {"INFL", "GRO"}] // Normal // Values;
withDates = TemporalData[econ, {times}]

dist = MultinormalDistribution[{m1, m2}, {{s11, s12}, {s21, s22}}];
class = HiddenMarkovProcess[2, dist];
eproc = EstimatedProcess[withDates, class]


(*HiddenMarkovProcess[{1., 
  0.}, {{0.971484, 0.0285164}, {0.0149025, 
   0.985098}}, {MultinormalDistribution[{4.52507, 
    1.17451}, {{12.1679, 4.53059}, {4.53059, 9.59945}}], 
  MultinormalDistribution[{2.59115, 
    3.40876}, {{1.12483, 0.156499}, {0.156499, 0.413983}}]}]*)
```

Then grab the emission PDF at each month and plot with observed data:

```
pdf[time_, x_, y_] = PDF[SliceDistribution[eproc, time], {x, y}];

plotPoints = 
  ListLinePlot3D[Flatten /@ withDates["Path"], PlotStyle -> Red];
dp3 = DensityPlot3D[
   pdf[time, x, y], {time, 1, Length@econ}, {x, -5, 15}, {y, -10, 10},
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"time", "inflation", "growth"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], 
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> p], 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"];
Show[dp3, plotPoints]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the transition matrix is nearly an Identity matrix, so the model doesn't change state very much.

Comment: @Elliot note that I had to make an update because I was wrong in assuming the dates are evenly spaced. It has been corrected now.

Comment: Thanks again for the great answer! The key was using TemporalData rather than a simple numerical matrix. I also prefer to work with raw numbers. So using a structure like TemporalData in place of a matrix didn't occur to me. Unfortunately, this is not well documented and I'd argue shouldn't matter.

As for the model itself, I'm positive that the 2-states is not enough. I was trying to start simple to fix EstimatedProcess. I'd guess that there are 4 states (i.e. 2x2), but that paper I linked found 7 states (with 3 being transitionary states).

Thanks also for that awesome visualization!